# How to prepare this data for the LSTM? (input_shape)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I have a large dataset, similar to the following:

```
Time Measurement Result
1    3.5         1
2    -5.0        2
3    3.0         1
4    3.2         5
5    -2.0        2
```

I drop the time column because it is uniform, and then, i intend to correlate the Measurement to the Result, using a LSTM model, but mostly of the guides and tutorials in the internet uses the Measurement to forecast a future Measurement, so how can i prepare this data to given Measurement it tries to determine the Result?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try indexing by measurement first.

```
df.set_index('Measurement',inplace=True)
```

Then you fit your model
Finally, during prediction, you can use

```
input_values=df['measurement']
```

do the prediction
Hope this helps